# How to pull JSON data on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to pull some information from an HTML page that has a script with JSON data in there. The script looks like this:

```
<script>
window.miPage = new pageInfo();
Details.initialize({
   "firstName":"John",
   "lastName":"Doe",
   "timeFormat":["am","pm"],
   "dateFormat":"M/d/yyyy",
   "locale":"en"
 });
</script>
```

I'm hoping to be able to pull the `lastName` value of `"Doe"` into a variable and use that as part of a jQuery or JS function.

Note, I can't modify the original script above.
Thanks!

Comment: Where are the variables inside the JSON defined?

Comment: Not sure, I believe all that comes from some  Ajax resource. I thought I would be able to just scan the HTML page for Last name inside Details.initialize

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with DOM.

```
for(let script of document.querySelectoAll("script")) {
  if(script.ismyscript) { // a way to find out if it is the one, you can ignore it
    let match = script.innerHTML.match(/^\s*Details\.initialize\((.*)\);$/m);
    if(match) {
      let json = match[1];
      console.log(JSON.parse(json))
    }
  }
}
```